# Is there a tool to find unused resources in an Android project?

Tags: android, resources, find

I'd like to find any unused resources in my Android project - this includes strings, ids, drawables, integers etc.

Does a tool to do this currently exist (preferably for Eclipse)?

Comment: https://github.com/KeepSafe/android-resource-remover

Comment: You can try this [programm](https://github.com/matzuk/RemovingAndroidUnusedResources) for android projects

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you use IntelliJ, which has Android support in the free community edition, you can do this by opening the generated R.java file (gen/R.java).  The unused resources will be marked with a warning for not being referenced anywhere in your project.

I'd be surprised if Eclipse doesn't do the same thing.

Comment: Eclipse does not do this. I'll give Intelli-J a go later.

Comment: I highly recommend it.  It doesn't have ddms integrated into the IDE, but LogCat is there.  ddms can just be launched from the command line or explorer.

Comment: In IntelliJ IDEA, the R.java file in gen/ is empty, even after rebuilding the project.

Comment: Tool based on android lint - https://github.com/KeepSafe/android-resource-remover

Comment: Eclipse absolutely does this. It uses the same technology as IntelliJ does.

Comment: This is the accepted answer, but as stated by copolii below R.java shows resources unused in java code only. If a resource is used in a layout it won't be registered by the IDE and will be marked as 'unused' in R.java... So this isn't te right answer to me.

Answer (score 34):

A friendly note: The IntelliJ idea ONLY works for resources that are not referenced in JAVA code. So if you have 1500 resources and only 20 are referenced directly from your java code, you end up with 1480 unused warnings in that file.

I'm seeing things marked as unused that I can clearly see are in use in various layouts. So keep that in mind ... don't go on a deleting spree.

Comment: this is an old question and all, but I don't see much development on the matter recently. Is there a way to find unused resources in a safe Java/XML/other-references way?

Answer (score 34):

Update to ADT 16 and use [Android Lint](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint). It is really amazing tool.

> Android Lint is a new tool for ADT 16 (and Tools 16) which scans Android project sources for potential bugs.

```
Here are some examples of the types of errors that it looks for:

- Missing translations (and unused translations)
- Layout performance problems (all the issues the old layoutopt tool used to find, and more)
- Unused resources
- Inconsistent array sizes (when arrays are defined in multiple configurations)
- Accessibility and internationalization problems (hardcoded strings, missing contentDescription, etc)
- Icon problems (like missing densities, duplicate icons, wrong sizes, etc)
- Usability problems (like not specifying an input type on a text field)
- Manifest errors
and many more.
```

Comment: Yep am using Android Lint now. Wasn't available when I first asked the question. Glad the Android SDK is improving a lot

Answer (score 19):

Andrei Buneyeu is right to Android Lint is the way to go. To specifically answer the question for anyone else looking, the command is:

`lint --check UnusedResources <path to project>`

There are a lot more options in lint that you can see with `lint --list`.

Comment: Not of much use when you need to delete hundreds of strings.

Comment: True. As far as I know, there isn't a switch in lint or another tool to automatically delete them.

Comment: For anyone using gradle, now there's "gradlew lint", which produces nice html and xml.

Comment: @AndroidDev Coming back to this, you could probably write something with `sed` and `xargs`. It wouldn't be pretty, but you could make it work.

Comment: With `Gradle 0.11.+`, I was able to run `./gradlew :mymodule:lint` and get the nice HTML and XML files in `mymodule/build/generated/`.

Answer (score 5):

[android-unused-resources](http://code.google.com/p/android-unused-resources) is a Java tool that will detect unused resources, and tell you where they are located.  It processes Java and XML files, so it avoids the problem in the accepted answer.

It's not perfect, but as long as you don't dynamically load resources ([getIdentifier](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier)(`java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String`)), It shouldn't tell you to delete any that are actually being used (although you'll get a compiler error even if that happens).