# Automatically removing unreferenced strings from strings.xml

Tags: android, resources

In my Android app I have a lot of strings in strings.xml that never get used because I removed the code modules that referenced them. Is there an automatic way in Eclipse or using some other tool that will remove those strings?

Comment: May be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824357/is-there-a-tool-to-find-unused-resources-in-an-android-project

Comment: You can do this using Android Lint : http://tools.android.com/tips/lint.

Comment: I'm not looking to find these unused texts but to automatically have them removed. The Lint tool doesn't do that.

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in $(lint . | grep 'The resource R.string.* appears to be unused' | perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if /R.string.(.*) appears/'); do  perl -pi -e 's/.*<string name="'$i'".*\n//' res/values*/strings.xml; done
```

Comment: You should add explanations to improve your answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Android Lint](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint) can do it for you. Try: Right clic on your project > Android Tools > Run Lint: Check for Common Errors. Depending on your Lint settings, the unused strings will be shown.

Comment: As my post stated, I'm looking for something that "automatically" removes these unreferenced text. The Lint tool only shows that it is unreferenced. I still have to manually go in and remove those items.